# 'IServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GetService'

Tags: sxa, validation

This is the first time i deal with custom validations, but I need to create a unique email validation using sitecore 9.0.2 and SXA 1.7.1 so i was following this tutorial

http://sitecoresolution.blogspot.com/2018/04/sitecore-9-forms-server-validation-email-already-exists.html

but i have a problem with this method:

```
protected virtual IFormDataProvider FormDataProvider
    {
        get
        {
            IFormDataProvider formDataProvider = this._dataProvider;
            if (formDataProvider == null)
            {
                IFormDataProvider service = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFormDataProvider>();
                IFormDataProvider formDataProvider1 = service;
                this._dataProvider = service;
                formDataProvider = formDataProvider1;
            }
            return formDataProvider;
        }
    }
```

specifically this line:

```
IFormDataProvider service = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFormDataProvider>();
```

saying that:

> 'IServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GetService' and the best extension method overload 'DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(IDependencyResolver)' requires a receiver of type 'IDependencyResolver'

Any ideas what might be the cause ?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll`?

Comment: No , i didn't. i only had the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection not the abstractions. Thank you , that fixed it.

Comment: Comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a reference `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` to your project.

It's not enough to have `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll` referenced only.

Answer (score 6):

Add "using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" to your usings should solve it. I had the same problem and VS didn't added it automatically.

Comment: i did have the reference to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll and was using it but it was not working. Turns out i should use instead Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll reference like @Marek Musielak suggested and add the using like you suggested.Thank you for your help.